# AngularJS: Select directive validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a directive with select template but i need the "name" tag so i can put a validation and i don't know how to add that. I tried adding attr but it didn't work.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jemaineosia/jJRfw/8/)

```
<form name="newForm" ng-submit="save()">
                <div>
                    Name: <input required ng-model="newSupplier.Name" name="myName" type="text" required/>
                    <span ng-show="newForm.myName.$error.required">*</span>
                    <br />
                    Status: <keywords name="myStatus" title="Choose Status" label="" array="myKeyword" keyword-type="ActivityType" supplier-id="newSupplier.Id" opt-value="Id" opt-description="Description"></keywords>
                    <span ng-show="newForm.myStatus.$error.required">*</span>
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit">Save</button>
                    <br /><i>How to save the ID of the selected dropdown?</i>
                    </div>
                    </form>
```

JS

```
app.directive('keywords', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            array: '=',
            supplierId : '='
        },
        template:   '<label>{{label}}</label>' +
        '<select ng-model="supplierId" ng-options="a[optValue] as a[optDescription] for a in array | filter: keywordType">' +
                        '<option style="display: none" value="">-- {{title}} --</option>' +
                    '</select>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.label = attrs.label;  
            scope.title = attrs.title;
            scope.optValue = attrs.optValue;
            scope.optDescription = attrs.optDescription;
            scope.keywordType = attrs.keywordType;
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add "required" to your "keywords" directive to make validation works.

```
template: '<label>{{label}}</label>' +
          '<select ng-model="supplierId" ng-options="a[optValue] as a[optDescription] for a in array | filter: keywordType" required>' +
          '<option style="display: none" value="">-- {{title}} --</option>' +
          '</select>',
```

This is the updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jJRfw/9/)

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: i have a problem with this fix. After I added a novalidate in the form then the dropdown is not working anymore. I think i need to pass the "name" value of the dropdown for it to work.

now my problem is, how can i pass the "Name" atttribute in my directive? i tried adding attr in scope but it's not working.

[this is my last test](http://jsfiddle.net/jemaineosia/jJRfw/10/)

Comment: What does dropdown is not working mean? I test your demo and dropdown works well. You mean you only want dropdown list to be validated?

Comment: on my real application I am using novalidate in my form and i forgot to add that in the fiddle. I think the only way to fix this is to provide info in the NAME attributes of the Select directive and i dont know how to do that. [this is the latest code](http://jsfiddle.net/jemaineosia/jJRfw/10/)

Comment: You can fetch the name attribute of directive by invoke attrs.name in select directive link function.

Comment: I've done that but it's not working..maybe i'm doing it wrong, [check my code here](http://jsfiddle.net/jemaineosia/jJRfw/10/)